# rich:select on drop down jump to the currently selected item in list

Tags: html, jsf, richfaces

We are using `rich:select` for our drop down inputs.

```
<rich:select id="select" value="#{controller.attrs.value}" >
       <f:selectItems value="#{controller.attrs.items}" var="foo"
            itemValue="#{foo}" itemLabel="#{foo.bar}" />
       <f:ajax event="#{ajaxActionController.action}" render="input" />            
</rich:select>
```

Our problem is that when the drop down is triggered it always starts with the first element in the list. However we would like it to jump to the position of the currently selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible through conventional means, but this should work:

```
<rich:select id="select" onlistshow="L.scrollList()" onlistclick="L.saveId()">
```

…

```
L = window.L || {};

(function() {        
    id = 0;    

    L.saveId = function() {
        id = #{ rich:component('select') }.list.index;
    };

    L.scrollList = function() {
        var list = #{ rich:component('select') }.list,
            listDiv = $( #{ rich:component('select') }.popupList.popup ).find(".rf-sel-lst-scrl"),
            selectedDivPos = $(list.items[id]).position();  

            listDiv.scrollTop(selectedDivPos.top - 7);
    };  

})(L);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a spin on Monday, off from work for the weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:inputHidden id="selectedId" value="#{controller.attrs.value}"/>
<rich:select id="select" value="#{controller.attrs.value}" >
   <f:selectItems value="#{controller.attrs.items}" var="foo"
        itemValue="#{foo}" itemLabel="#{foo.bar}" />
   <f:ajax event="#{ajaxActionController.action}" render="selectedId input" />
```

Make an `<h:inputHidden/>` and add its id (`selectedId` in this example ) to `"render="` of ajax, then `<h:inputHidden/>` value will be updated in case of a new selection.

Now you can get the value of `<h:inputHidden/>` (the selected value of `</rich:select>` ) in javascript:

```
var selectedValue = document.getElementById('selectedId').value;
```