# rich:select opens on first item instead of selected

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have a `rich:select` in my code as follows :

```
<rich:select style="width: 50" enableManualInput=false value="#{MyBean.Obj.id}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.objList}"/>
</rich:select>
```

On my page, if I open this dropdown, it shows the first element in the dropdown instead of that specified by the value attribute. If I now select one of the elements and then open it again, it still goes to the first element, not the selected one.

If I however replace `rich:select` with `h:selectOneMenu` with all the same attributes, it works fine. I can't use `h:selectOneMenu` though as the *richfaces* styles are not applied to it.

#### Is there anyway I can get rich:select working or apply the richfaces styles to h:selectOneMenu?

Comment: It shows just one element instead of the whole list?

Comment: No, it shows the entire list in the dropdown as it should.The problem is if the list contains one,two,three,four,five and value=three.The list opens as if one is selected not three.In other words it always shows the first element as selected when opened.Sorry if this was unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h:selectOneMenu` generates `<select>` and that [can't be styled very well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript).

The `<rich:select>` doesn't have that kind of functionality, but it can be achieved with Javascript, take a look on [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718796/richselect-on-drop-down-jump-to-the-currently-selected-item-in-list/17723491#17723491) for a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use converter attribute of rich:select. Sometime I have same issues and always it is because rich:select fail mapping to appropriate value (in your situation it is three).

Answer (score 0):

change `<f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.objList}"/>` to `<f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.objList}" var="obj" itemValue="obj.id"/>`

and if your id is not a native Java class, then implement `hashCode` and `equals` method in it

Comment: This doesn't explain this part of the question: *"If I however replace rich:select with h:selectOneMenu with all the same attributes, it works fine"*