# How to scroll options list in rich select using java script or jquery?

Tags: richfaces

I have an issue with rich:select component RichFaces 4.0.0.Final.

after scrolling and selecting list item that is down in the list, if I opened the list again, the list does't scroll automatically to the selected item. I have to scroll manually.

Any help!

Comment: What version of RichFaces are using? As far as I recall this was implemented in some micro-release of RichFaces 4.5.

Comment: RichFaces 4.0.0.Final

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rich:select on drop down jump to the currently selected item in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718796/richselect-on-drop-down-jump-to-the-currently-selected-item-in-list)

Comment: Not exactly, but this guided me to a different work around, will drop it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding __onBtnMouseDown function of select.js fixed the issue:

```
__onBtnMouseDown: function(e) {
if(!this.popupList.isVisible()) {
    var selectedSymbol = this.__getValue();
    var selectedSymbolIndex;
    var offset = 0;

    // loop over list to get selected symbol index
    for (var i = 0; i < this.cache.originalValues.length; i++) {
        if(this.cache.originalValues[i] == selectedSymbol){
            selectedSymbolIndex = i;
        }
    }

    if(this.items.length > 0 && this.enableManualInput) {
        $(document.getElementById(this.id+"Items")).empty().append(this.items);
    }

    this.__showPopup();

    if(selectedSymbolIndex >= 0){
        offset = selectedSymbolIndex * this.items.get(selectedSymbolIndex).offsetHeight;
        this.popupList.__selectByIndex(selectedSymbolIndex);
        var parentContainer = $(document.getElementById(this.id + "Items")).parent()[0];
        parentContainer.scrollTop = offset;
    }

} else {
    this.__hidePopup();
}
this.isMouseDown = true;
}
```